# APPLIED a CSS style after adding a class to an element via classList.toggle("element")

Tags: javascript, css

I try to make a hamburger menu but I struggle to get it working properly.

My starting point is this animation https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_menu_icon_js and in a first time I just want to add a behavior : set opacity: 0; to another div (the content of the menu).

I thought adding the class="change" to this div and the proper CSS rules could make the job but despite the class being applied, only the "menu button" take the new CSS, not the content div. Is anybody know what missed ?

Here is a codepen of what I did : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pBBNaV

```
.change .overlay-content {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is your css select for the div that you want to fade.

You have: `.change .overlay-content` which will find a an element with class overlay-content inside an element with class change.

What you need is `.change.overlay-content` (notice the removed space) which finds an element with both the classes change and overlay-content.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eooggO